# How to sync two ArrayLists in Java?

Tags: java, android, performance, list, arraylist

I have two ArrayList. I want to sync the lists with the latest data between them. Basically, my objective is to sync local DB with my backend. So I want to replace the local DB with latest data and vice-versa. What is the effective way (with minimum loops) to sync those two lists?

In detail: if my first list has 15 items and the second one has 9. Then I want to make two lists with 15 items each and at the same time with the latest data.

My CustomObject:

```
public class CustomObject {
    private String uniqueId;
    private Date updatedAt;

    public String getUniqueId() {
        return uniqueId;
    }

    public void setUniqueId(String uniqueId) {
        this.uniqueId = uniqueId;
    }

    public Date getUpdatedAt() {
        return updatedAt;
    }

    public void setUpdatedAt(Date updatedAt) {
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean when you are saying "latest data"? i didnt figure out.. can you give a real example?

Comment: why do you need to lists if they hold the same data? Also, by data, do you mean the same objects, or objects that have the same values for their members?

Comment: @Nirel I mean my Custom object has other fields say description. So if description changes for an Item which exists in both the lists, then I need to make sure the latest timestamp and put the latest description.

Comment: @njzk2 My backend is Parse. So it returns the parse objects as a list. Also I get List from my local DB. Thats the reason

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want, you are trying to build a single list with the most recent data from 2 lists? Lots of ways to do this, here is one using a map:

```
List<CustomObject> list // retrieved from local db
list.addAll(getListFromBackendDb());
Map<String, CustomObject> mappy = new HashMap<>();
for (CustomObject co : list) {
    CustomObject existing = mappy.get(co.getUniqueId());
    if (existing == null || co.getUpdatedAt().compareTo(existing.getUpdated()) > 0) {
        mappy.put(co.getUniqueId(), co);
    }
}
return new ArrayList<>(mappy.values());
```

Comment: What I meant was, I have to compare the two lists for updated items and new items and insert new/updated items in local DB and push the new/updated items to the backend. From the code you posted, does the list hold all the items from both local DB and backend ??